# Saving a binary search tree to disk

Tags: c, binary-tree

When trying to save the contents of a tree to file, nothing is saved and I don't know why.
These are the function calls I'm making:

```
insert(tree, cust.id, filePos);
saveTree(tree, "cIndex.dat", 0);
```

And these are the functions involved:

```
struct NODE *insert(struct NODE *node, char info[], int pos) 
{ 
int length = strlen(info);
// 1. If the tree is empty, return a new, single node 
if (node == NULL) 
{ 
    struct INFO stuff; 
    //stuff = (struct INFO*)malloc(sizeof(struct INFO));

    strncpy(stuff.data, info, DATA_LENGTH);
    stuff.filePos = pos;

    node = malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));

    node->data = stuff; 
    node->left = NULL; 
    node->right = NULL;

    return(node); 

}    

else 
{ 
    // 2. Otherwise, recur down the tree 
    if (strncmp(info, node->data.data, length) <= 0) 
    {
        node->left = insert(node->left, info, pos); 
    }

    else 
    {
        node->right = insert(node->right, info, pos);
    }

    return(node); // return the (unchanged) node pointer 
} 
}


int saveTree(struct NODE *node, char filename[], int posInFile) 
{
FILE *file;
file = fopen(filename, "r+b"); //r+ so as to overwrite existing data instead of appending

char c;
char posStr[POS_LENGTH];

fseek(file, posInFile, SEEK_SET);

while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
{
    if(node != NULL)
    {
        fseek(file, -1, SEEK_CUR);

        fwrite(node->data.data, sizeof(char), DATA_LENGTH, file);
        sprintf(posStr, "%d", node->data.filePos); 
        fwrite(posStr, sizeof(char), POS_LENGTH, file);

        posInFile = ftell(file);

        saveTree(node->left, filename, posInFile);
        saveTree(node->right, filename, posInFile);
    }
}

fclose(file);

return 1;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps check those file API's to start with?

Comment: A useful trick here--if you want to preserve the structure (say you've balanced it)--is to use the identification of arrays as implicit arrays (element zero is the root, 1 is root->left, 2 is root->right, 3 is root->left->left, 4 is root->left->right, 5 is root->right->left and so on).

Answer (score 0):

It could be a few things.  From your last question, I noticed that you do not actually store the tree you create (in `loadTree`).  Have you fixed that?

But just looking at your save function...  You should open the file once and pass the `FILE*` recursively.  To make this easy, do it outside and pass the `FILE*` instead of the name.  You are using buffered output without flushing, and you are going to run into trouble otherwise.

```
int saveTree( struct NODE *node, FILE *fp );

// ...

FILE *fp = fopen( filename, "wb" );
saveTree( tree, fp );
fclose(fp);
```

Is there a reason you're writing binary files with text values?  Are you sure you don't want to open in text mode and use `fprintf`?

Comment: Nope.. I forgot to store the tree. But by storing do you mean tree = insert(tree, cust.id, filePos)? Because I tried that and it resulted in an infinite loop.

Edit: The binary file is a requirement

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.  Put it this way, if you *don't* store it, then you have no tree.  Therefore, when you try to write it to file, surprise!!  The file is empty!  Would you rather avoid an infinite loop by leaking your entire tree into a collection of isolated nodes, or would you like to build your tree and then try to work out where your infinite loop is occurring?

Comment: I would appreciate any help I can get at this point. I've already tried finding out why the infinite loop was happening, to no avail, though I know its the while loop in the saveTree function. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, the idea is to put `printf` calls in places where you think you might have problems, and output relevant values.  That way you can determine for yourself where your program might be going wrong and why.  This is a very simple and common method of debugging that doesn't require knowledge of any debugging tools.

Comment: ...how do you think I traced the cause to the while loop? Irregardless, I'm still stuck :(

Comment: So you know it's the `while` loop..  Now keep digging.  Go inside the loop.  Look at important values.  If it's not terminating then write out the values that ought to be changing that should cause it to terminate.  If you persevere, you are sure to solve it.

Comment: Thing is, after I forcefully terminated the program and checked the output , it repeatedly wrote the same string to file. So I think the node became its own child node. I have no clue how that happened, I'm very new to C and abstract data types aren't my forte.

Comment: So then you double check that by writing out the pointer values of the node and its two children (use `%p` to write a pointer).  Then you work out why that happened by putting in similar code early on (for example, when you build your tree).  Another hint, if you are on Linux, is to pipe your program through `more` so you have time to read each page of data.